# Redundant routes between switches

Tags: networking, home-networking, wireless-access-point

I have a relatively simple (home) network setup.

Downstairs:

```
Ubiquiti Edgerouter X
Ubiquiti AP (NanoHD)
+clients (wired and wireless)
```

Upstairs

```
Unmanaged gigabit switch
Ubiquiti AP (AC Lite)
+ clients (wired and wireless)
```

Downstairs the router is wired to the AP, and is also wired to a powerline plug to connect to the upstairs switch.

Upstairs the AP is wired into the unmanaged switch.

My issue is that the powerline adapters every so often will drop their connection, requiring a power cycle to recover.  The Ubiquiti support wired backhaul but I haven't enabled it (yet).

I would like the network to be tolerant of any failures of the powerline plugs.  If both the upstairs AP and the powerline effectively are connecting upstairs to downstairs through the upstairs switch, will that a) work, b) will clients be able to 'get to downstairs' and out to the internet through the remaining "good" link (i.e. either the wired AP backhaul or the powerline) in the event of a failure?

If not what is my best upgrade option - will a managed switch help me here?  I'm trying to avoid putting holes through the walls by running an ethernet cable.

Comment: Are you sure you mean “wired backhaul”? Not wireless? Because if you could get it wired, surely you’d have done so already. // Switching loops are a recipe for disaster.

Comment: I'm just reading up about switching loops, as always it helps to know the term to be able to google it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you connect two switches on two connections simultaneously you will create a loop (simply speaking two possible paths your "network packages" can take). Theoretically, there are three possibilities to solve this, assuming you currently (or future) switch support them:

- "loop prevention" (there are several implementations, start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switching_loop) for more info)
- use link aggregation
- separate the two connections via vlan

Now to the practical bit:

- loop prevention should work fine and is supported by a lot of routers
- link aggregation is rather theoretical since I haven't heard of any solutions to aggregate different types of "connections"
- vlan will be tricky since you need to "reconnect" them via a router this has the considerable drawback of fragmenting your network and will be much more complicated to set it up

Comment: do you know whether the loop prevention will kick in only when required? i.e. in normal circumstances there will be a loop which is blocked (only one route back downstairs), but as soon as one of the links fails will the remaining good link automatically start fowarding packets? Or would the MAC table need to be cleared first? i.e. automatic rather than a manual process?

Comment: @Rich yes, simply speaking it will automatically "kick in" (or in this case "out"). The switch will handle changes to it's MAC address table by itself and makes all necessary adjustments. No manual intervention is necessary (if you take a LAN cable from one port and put it into another, it's essentially the same thing in regards to handling the changes, no manual intervention is necessary there either)

Comment: there are a lot of good explanations on how this works in detail if you wanna know more [here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sdYDLip2ANI) just one of many examples (I haven't reviewed it, it's just a pointer where you can start)

Answer (score 0):

There is not much that you can do to improve powerline adapters connectivity.

What you can do:

1. Install the latest firmware for the Powerline adapters
2. Check whether the powerline adapters are working properly
   by connecting the two on one power-strip with one connected
   to the router. After some suitable time survey the router's log for disconnections.
3. Reducing interference in the home's power supply:

   - Plug the powerline adapter directly into a wall outlet without power strip or extension cord.
   - Avoid powerline connections on different phases, fuse boxes etc.
   - Avoid possible sources of interference on the same power circuit such as
     switch mode power supplies, halogen systems and energy-saving lamps,
     but mainly appliances with electric motors.
   - Ensure that cables carrying VDSL signal are distanced from electrical
     wiring and outlets.
   - Test different wall outlets and reduce the distance between the
     powerline adapters.
4. If the powerline adapters may disconnect after a long period of idling with no
   traffic, create a scheduled task that will periodically ping some device through
   the adapters.
5. Use instead of powerline a strong wifi router that can punch through to the
   upper floor. For better covering of distance use the 2.4Ghz band,
   although 5Ghz is faster (but worse at going through obstacles).

If all these measures don't help or are not applicable, perhaps your wiring schema
is not favorable for powerline adapters, so a direct cable is required.

Answer (score -1):

If you have 2 ether over power adapters and replace downstairs switch to a managed switch, you can use STP and create Trunks to allow for redundant cable ties between the two switches.

Otherwise, you are outta luck.  Doing 2 connections creates a round robin.